# Multiple union notation problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define $\{S_i\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ to be a sequence of sets such that $S_0 = \{0\}$ and $S_i =\bigcup\limits_{k=0}^{i-1} \{S_k\}$. Find the number of brackets of the power set of $S_4$ if the null set is written as $\{\}$.

I am confused on how to go about this problem. I suppose $S_1 = \{\{0\}\}$? And is $S_2 = \{\{\{0\},0\}\}$? Or is it equal to $\{\{\{0\}\},\{0\}\}$?

Answer (score 2):

First, here is what the definition gives us:
\begin{align}
S_0&=\{0\}\\
S_1&=\{S_0\}=\{\ \{0\}\ \}\\
S_2&=\{S_0\}\cup\{S_1\}=\{S_0,S_1\}=\{\ \{0\},\ \{\{0\}\}\ \}\\
S_3&=\{S_0\}\cup\{S_1\}\cup\{S_2\}=\{S_0,S_1,S_2\}=\dots\\
\vdots&\quad\vdots
\end{align}

On the other hand, we could be smarter, as we just need to find the number of brackets. Note that the number of brackets in $S_n$ is two more than the sum of the number of brackets of all $S_i$ with $i<n$: we put all the sets next to each other and add two outer brackets.

Hence we get the number of brackets $b(S_n)$:
\begin{align}
b(S_0) &= 2\\
b(S_1) &= 2 + 2 = 4\\
b(S_2) &= 2 + 2 + 4 = 8\\
b(S_3) &= 2 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 16\\
b(S_4) &= 2 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 32
\end{align}

It's easy to see that $b(S_n)=2^{n+1}$ for all $n$.

---

This is only half of the problem, as we need to find the number of brackets in the *power set* of $S_4$.

Note that $\mathcal P(S_4)=\mathcal P(\{S_0,S_1,S_2,S_3\})$ is the following set:
\begin{align}
\{\quad &\{\},\\
&\{S_0\},
\{S_1\},
\{S_2\},
\{S_3\},\\
&\{S_0,S_1\},
\{S_0,S_2\},
\{S_0,S_3\},
\{S_1,S_2\},
\{S_1,S_3\},
\{S_2,S_3\},\\
&\{S_0,S_1,S_2\},
\{S_0,S_1,S_3\},
\{S_0,S_2,S_3\},
\{S_1,S_2,S_3\},\\
&\{S_0,S_1,S_2,S_3\}\quad\}
\end{align}

It contains $2^4=16$ sets, thus we get $2$ outer brackets for the whole power set, $2\cdot 16$ outer brackets for each subset of $S_4$, and since each set in $S_4$ is in exactly half of the sets in the power set, we get $8\cdot b(S_n)$ for each $0\leq n\leq 3$.

So in total: $2 + 32 + 8\cdot (2 + 4 + 8 +16)=274$.